# Save form input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple fields on a page. If a user fills in the fields and then decides to leave the page he/she will loose it. I'd like to add an alert using jQuery UI dialog to alert them about the data that has not been saved. I think I can get the buttons and dialog figured out. My question is: how do I detect them leaving the page without submitting the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939961/on-unload-event-of-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example - you need to be able to detect whether the form has been submitted as part of an onbeforeunload event.

```
var formSubmitted = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!formSubmitted) {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page without submitting the form"?);
    }
};

document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function () {
    formSubmitted = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event. However, keep in mind that some newer browsers like Firefox 4 do not allow you to customize the message that is displayed.

Comment: snap! I think we posted exactly the same time :-) Good point on the firefox 4 gotcha

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the onbeforeunload event, here is some Mozilla developer connection documention to get you started:  [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)